# Delete specific rows from BindingSource

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to remove all rows containing `Environment.Username` from my `BindingSource`.

Could anyone help me? Could anyone help me? I'm running the below code, but keep getting an index error (but I know the record exists):

```
If BS.Count > 0 Then
    Dim row As Integer = 0
    For Each BSRow As DataRowView In BS
        If DirectCast(BS(row), DataRowView)("NTUsername").ToString = Environment.UserName Then
            .RemoveAt(row)
        End If
        row += 1
    Next
End If
```

Edit: As per comments

```
If BS.Count > 0 Then
    For row As Integer = BS.Count To 0
        If DirectCast(BS(row), DataRowView)("NTUsername").ToString = Environment.UserName Then
            .RemoveAt(row)
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: You're editing inside iteration, which should cause an exception as soon as a row is removed, try use a `For` loop instead, and delete using the index from that

Comment: Hey guys, wow thanks for the super speedy response! I've made the change in my original post. Can you take a look please? I ran this, but it's not working. Not sure why since it looks like it should...

Comment: `For row As Integer = BS.Count -1 To 0 Step -1` Most things in .Net are zero based so count is one more than index.

Comment: Ah! Mary that worked! May I ask that you kindly make an answer please so that I can check it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For row As Integer = BS.Count -1 To 0 Step -1
```

Most things in .Net are zero based so count is one more than index.